# Gracefully kill a java (jetty/solr) process started from a windows batch file with "start /b"

Tags: windows, solr, batch-file, jetty, taskkill

I'm starting a Java background process (Solr) from a batch file with

```
start /b java -jar ...
```

The problem is that `start /b` will shield the process from SIGINT signals, see `help start`. This means that `taskkill /pid ...` won't work and `taskkill /f /pid ...` will kill the process without letting it execute shutdown hooks first.

Is there another way to start the background process on Windows from a .bat file without opening a window and without shielding it from SIGINT? Or is there another way of sending a signal to the java VM so that Solr shuts down gracefully when running from `start /b`?

I'd like to use a normal batch script rather than VBScript or similar if possible as this is what most our users probably know best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my specific case (solr + jetty), see http://alaminsumon.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/how-to-stop-and-start-jetty-server-from.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do it in a .bat file, but with Powershell you can do this:

```
Start-Process java -ArgumentList "-jar start.jar <args>" -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Then you can stop the process normally.

Run `get-help Start-Process -detailed` for more info on options - you can also easily run the process as a different user and other things that the old `start` won't let you do.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! :-) I'd rather avoid having to depend on Powershell, though, see question.

Comment: Thanks, Dan! I didn't realize that my URL got truncated. Should be fixed now. Upvoted your answer because it will probably help others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested that? I ran:

```
START /B notepad.exe
```

and then closed it using

```
TASKKILL /PID 123456
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, that works. Unfortunately the same is not true for the case I described. When I use `start java ...`, taskkill works, not so if I use `start /b java ...`. Maybe the difference is that notepad opens a window while my process runs with its output redirected to a log file?